# Dark texture when importing .FBX from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm trying to import an Blender object with texture to Unity.
I did a simple cube with smart UV Projet unwrap, i added a texture and then exported it as .FBX file.
When in Unity, even if the cube has the right material with the right texture, the cube has a dark version of the texture.

[Unity cube with dark shadowed texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUTx3.png)

[Blender cube with bright texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EYVq.png)

Here's what i tried:

- Flipping my normals in or out in Blender.
- Change normals and tangents settings in unity to calculate.
- Trying to change pretty much all Model settings in inspector in unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a guess, it looks a little bit like you have no light source in your Unity scene. If you want the texture brightness constant without factors like scene lighting you need to change the material to some unlit variant in unity.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the albedo tint of the material.  It seems that sometimes when extracting, it automatically adds a gray tint to it.
[MaterialInspectorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo6jK.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).